# Applescript to update existing mail rule

Tags: mac, applescript, macos-sierra

MacOS Sierra.

This seems like it would be possible based on the following script, which *creates* a new rule:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set newRule to make new rule at end of rules with properties { ... }
    tell newRule
        make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties { ... }
    end tell
end tell
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set existingRule to (* get a specific rule already in Mail Preferences *)
    tell existingRule
        make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:message content, qualifier:does contain value, expression:"woohoo"}
    end tell
end tell
```

What I cannot seem to find is a way to *retrieve* a rule that is already stored.

Comment: Are you trying to write a script that automatically checks for new email?

Comment: @music2myear: Nah. I was trying to figure out how to update an existing rule with a script. The answer below is correct - took me a very long time a circuitous route to find and figure out though.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you were able to figure it out and document it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this example, we are trying to get the sender of an email, then append that to an email rule that performs the same action if the email is in the list.

```
tell application "Mail"
    (* The nameOfJunkRule is the string you gave in Mail.app. *)
    (* This is the part that begins to address the question. *)
    set markAsJunkRule to get rule nameOfJunkRule

    (* Get the selected messages in Mail.app *)
    set theMessages to the selection

    repeat with theMessage in theMessages
        (* Get the sender of the message. *)
        set senderAddress to sender of theMessage

        (* We want to make sure the address isn't already in the list. *)
        set foundAddress to false
        repeat with theCondition in rule conditions of markAsJunkRule
            if senderAddress = expression of theCondition then
                set foundAddress to true
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat

        (* If we need to add a new address to the rule. This is to finish the answer. *)
        if foundAddress = false then
            tell markAsJunkRule
                make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {rule type:from header, qualifier:does contain value, expression:senderAddress}
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for this solution!